# Meteor: Whats the best way to test equality of two values (like {{#if someVar == 'someVal'}}) in Blaze?

Tags: javascript, meteor, templating

I'm having to define template helpers everywhere that simply test the equality of a document property with a constant so I can do something like this in my template:

```
    {{#if fruitIsPineapple}}...{{/if}}
```

And in my template helper looks like:

```
    Template.example.helpers({
      fruitIsPineapple: function () { return this.document.fruit === 'pineapple'; } 
    });
```

How can I save myself from having to create all these helpers? It'd be nice if there we an equality operator in Blaze...

Comment: A package that defines a lot of handy helpers, including one for testing equality: https://github.com/raix/Meteor-handlebar-helpers

Comment: Why did someone downvote this? I had the same question, and the answer is not documented anywhere.

Answer (score 50):

I had my question answered at the Meteor Devshop. Turns out you can define a Handlebars helper, like so:

```
    Template.registerHelper('equals', function (a, b) {
      return a === b;
    });
```

Then use it in prefix position like this:

```
    {{#if equals fruit 'pineapple'}}...{{/if}}
```

Comment: Doesn't it have to be `UI.registerHelper` now?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `Template.registerHelper` now? ;P

Comment: Sorry, I broke the up-counter from its {{equal up_counter 42}} state. \o>

Answer (score 16):

Without any cumbersome code, you can achieve this by installing [raix:handlebar-helpers](https://github.com/raix/Meteor-handlebar-helpers) and do something like this:

```
{{#if $eq a b}}
   ...
{{ /if }}
```